# Using one variable as an another variable of different data type but the same name

Tags: java, design-patterns, reflection, data-structures

I am using a class where I am taking input as the file name and the file location. I have a pre defined file names, so I will match the predefined file names with the file name that I received and then store the values accordingly. Please look at the code below

```
//Set of storage maps and tables 
public class storage
{
//Storage set
public static Set<Integer> tiger = new HashSet<Integer>();

//Storage set
public static Set<Integer> lion = new HashSet<Integer>();

//This is the table used for storing the browser customer count  
public static Table<String,String,Integer> elephant = HashBasedTable.create(); 

//Storage map 
public static Map<String, String> monkey = new HashMap<String, String>();


public static void storeDataDirector(String fileLocation,String fileName) throws     Exception 
{
    if (fileName = monkey) 
                **update the "monkey map"**

}
```

This is my problem, also I have lot of maps and tables to be used so I wouldn't be able to use multiple if conditions and then check and update the same.

What I would like to know is the below

As I have said earlier, The file name that I am sending to the program which is "String filename" has the same name of the "Map monkey" but the former is a String and the latter is the map. **I would like to know if I will be able to use the string variable as a reference to the map instance as both of them have the same name** . This will highly avoid the if conditions that I am using in the program and thus I would like to possible solution for this ... Anything related to type caseting ort

Comment: First of all, `=` is no a comparison, but an assignment. Second: Use `"monkey".equals(fileName)` for String comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to relate them in a Map, and use the file name as a key for example

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>>
//  file    store structure
```

If you need a generic solution, you could solve this by implementing an abstraction of your store structure, by implementing an interface similar to this one:

```
// T is the store type and U is the original type (String from file for instance...)
public interface StoreUnit<T, U> {

    void update(U record);

    List<T> list();

}
```

so you will have an implementation for each case (Set, Map, Table ...) and will relate it in a map using the file name as key.

```
monkeyFileName => MapStoreUnit<Entry<String,String>,String>
tigerFileName => SetStoreUnit<Integer, String>
elephantFileName => TableStoreUnit<Entry<Entry<String,String>,String>,String> // not sure if for Table there is something better than Entry ;)
```

When you wanna update some store you perform a `get` over the map using the file name as key, and invoking `update` method implemented with the record (that could be an `String`, complex `Object`) and so on. When you need to read something from there you could use the `list` method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have another `Map` - whose key is a `String` and value is a `Map`. Something like `Map<String,Map> allMaps = new HashMap<String,Map>()`

Once you have this map , populate it with all your filenames and the corresponding maps `monkey`.

`allMaps .put("monkey", monkey)`

If a string filename corresponds to not a `map` but to a `set` , then you need to declare something more general `Map<String,Object> allMaps = new HashMap<String,Object>()`. Ofcourse this means you need to cast the value to its particular type before you can do any meaningful thing with it.

Then , to use this map , use your filename argument

`Map monkeyAgain =  allMaps.get(filename)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection:

```
Storage.class.getField(fileName).get(null)
```

You will still have to cast the returned object. I do not think this the right approach.

Comment: +1 for "this is not the right approach."  The OP really ought to rethink the design here.